# Checking the Web API's Response Always Returns 500 Error (without an Error on Server)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dotnet-httpclient, dynamics-crm-online

Every time I send a request, the response says it had a 500 Server Error. However, I control both sides of this process, and the server is not erroring. Ideas?!

Here's how we setup the HttpClient to send the request. BTW, this Client is hosted in Microsoft's Dynamix CRM Online (in case that makes a difference):

```
client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
```

And this is how we call it, from CRM Online, and get the response:

```
var task = client.PostAsyncSecurely("api/Invoices/CreateInvoice/", iHelper);
var result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Yes, we created our own extension, but all it does is convert the model we pass in to send across (and it's working, according to the receiving API).

```
public static Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncSecurely(this System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, string requestUri, System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent content)
{
    return client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
}
```

We've tried creating responses multiple ways, in the Web API on our server, to no avail:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateInvoice([FromBody]Object invoiceHelper)

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Comment: Is it getting into your ControllerMethod?

Comment: It is getting into my Controller Action, and all the way through it, at least to where the response is returned.

Comment: Also, there is nothing in the Window's Event Logs. And Nothing in these IIS logs, either:  C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Comment: Can you use `Fiddler` (or any HTTP traffic monitoring tool) to confirm that the request is being sent correctly?

Comment: The Request is reaching our API correctly, and being processed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To use Dynamics CRM Online WebAPI, you need to register your application as an allow app in teh Azure AD of your tenant ([Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-samples-csharp))

The other way to connect to Dynamics CRM Online is using the SDK (if you are using a .NET Language) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

Hope it helps

Comment: We are not calling to CRM. This is custom code hosted by CRM, calling to a local server.

Comment: Oh, Ok, are you invoking to an IP address directly ? or are you using the DNS address? dynamicscrm only supports external calls using DNS addresses

Comment: The call reaches the server, from the client in CRM. But when the server sends a response, no matter what the response is, the client that is loaded in CRM says it received a 500 error.